# html css example in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I wanted to use a [third-party html/css example](http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/) in Django, but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

EXAMPLE CODE

</body>
</html>
```

I have used just this example, and commented all other code. Django recognizes the css file, I checked it. However, I don't get a sticky footer and header. They transform in a plain text, just like the main body.

I put this example in the codeacademy engine and it works there as well.

What hidden stones of Django I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no hidden stones in django. there is no such option as recognize css file for django. Django has nothing to do with css files.

I recommend u to open network panel in browser developer tools console and check, was the css file downloaded successfully by browser or not.

in some case if u use django development server there is manual how to serve static files in development mode

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/

another cases are, misspelled css file name or misspelled/incorrect path to css file

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thank you and sorry for a stupid question! Your answer helped me to find the solution :) Unfortunately, I cannot vote - too low reputation.

Comment: sure, I'm new to this page, sorry.